# PHP, trying to get $_POST['var'] into table as text

Tags: php, mysql

i'm having trouble with the code below. it's been simplified to show the problem. i use a loop because the input names are identical and need to create multiple new rows in a mysql table. the problem is i'm using $_POST['name'][$i] and the table won't accept because it doesn't see it as 'text?, ...i think. 
like i said, code's been greatly simplified.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['url']); $i++) {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO urls (url) VALUES ('. $_POST['url'][$i].')'; 
    if(!mysql_query($sql)) {
    echo "error " . mysql_error();
    }
}
```

i tried to rememdy with this -

$sql = 'INSERT INTO urls (url) VALUES ('. '"'. $_POST['url'][$i].'"'. ')';

if i do this it works, there is no error

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO urls (url) VALUES (' " hello " ')';
```

this is probably a newbie type mistake, right? thanks for any help with this.

Comment: Post the html <form/> markup.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. I suggest you read up on the subject and (at the very least) escape your values by running them through  `mysql_real_escape_string()` before inserting.

Comment: Please do a `var_dump($_POST)` and post it for whatever query isn't working. Also, post the error you receive.

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner way (and the errors are fixed):

```
$urls = (isset($_POST['url']) && is_array($_POST['url'])) ? $_POST['url'] : array();
foreach($urls as $url) {
    if(!is_string($url)) {
        continue;
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO urls (url) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($url) . "')";
    if(!mysql_query($sql)) {
        echo "error " . mysql_error();
    }
}
```

Making sure the $_POST['url'] is an array will keep from trying to treat a non array (or non-existent key) as an array.  The is_string is to protect from a user trying to throw in a sub array to get PHP to throw a "using array as string" notice.  The escape is to avoid SQL injection, and the single quotes added are so MySQL knows it's a string.

Comment: I don't consider it a "nice guard" but rather necessary.  I code a bit on the paranoid side though :).

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add quotes around the POSTed value in your MySQL query like below. Also, if you don't escape the input, it's a massive SQL injection vulnerability:

```
$data = mysql_escape_string($_POST['url'][$i]);
$sql = 'INSERT INTO urls (url) VALUES ("'.$data.'")';
```

The query breaks MySQL because MySQL thinks your post value is supposed to be numeric without the quotes.

Comment: +1, i didn't know you could use double-quotes as a text delimiter in MySQL until I tested this....

Comment: They shouldn't typically be used.  Unless I'm remembering this incorrectly, ANSI SQL specifies that ' shall be used as string delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see that actual error message returned by mysql_error() but I think your problem is that you're not providing the $_POST value to the sql query as thought it's text.

try replacing

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO urls (url) VALUES ('. $_POST['url'][$i].')';
```

with

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO urls (url) VALUES ('". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['url'][$i]) ."')";
```

Comment: meh - my previous comment was stupid - given that it's from $_POST of course it's external input.  In my own defense I was planning on editing my entry but was testing @rdlowery's code - I always assumed that single quotes were the required text delimiter in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your $_POST variables before you insert them via an SQL statement, preferably using the [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function to fortify your query against [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection).

Comment: "prepared SQL statement" is kind of ambiguous there.  mysql_real_escape_string would not be used with a prepared statement.  It's obvious from context that that is not what you mean, but to the question asker it might be vague.

Comment: Also please note that `mysql_real_escape_string()` isn't a magic solution, some considerations still have to be made. In a query like `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT $count`, here escaping isn't sufficient. (`intval()` could be used here)

Comment: You're right. Bad word choice. I suppose that 'prepared' in the sense that it's arranged from a concatenation of string parts and variables is pretty much implied, whereas one could actually `prepare()` an SQL query using the PDO prepare method. I suppose here, the term is superfluous at best.

Comment: @KristianAntonsen agreed. That broad sloppy 'brush-strokes' mentality is the reason they're deprecating the Magic Quotes process. MRES will work for many situations, but techniques for escaping data should always be assessed on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by Corbin is good - however try not to fire insert queries in a loop.

You could create the sql query as one string and then fire the insert query once.

You could change your insert statement from 
insert into table (field) values(1);
insert into table (field) values(1);

To:
insert into table (field) values(1), (2), (3), (4)...

This is a more optimal solution - however mysql has a max length to which it can take sql statements - therefore use your best judgement.

Answer (score -2):

try this statement

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO urls (url) VALUES ('". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['url'][$i])."')";
```

Comment: use mysql_real_escape_string() on the post values before insertion